# i am not getting cpu load in percentage linux java

Tags: java, linux

hi i am trying to get cpu load but i am getting per value more then 100% not understanding what wrong i am doing .. .

as i am using core i3 and having two Virtual machines on it and on one VM i am doing this task my source code is,

```
public class PerformanceMonitor {

    static long lastSystemTime      = 0;
        static long lastProcessCpuTime  = 0;
        public static int  availableProcessors = ManagementFactory.getOperatingSystemMXBean().getAvailableProcessors();
      // public static int  availableProcessors = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
        public synchronized double getCpuUsage()
        {
            ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean().setThreadCpuTimeEnabled(true);
            if ( lastSystemTime == 0 )
            {
                baselineCounters();
              //  return ;
            }

            long systemTime     = System.nanoTime();
            long processCpuTime = 0;

            processCpuTime = ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean().getCurrentThreadCpuTime();
            double cpuUsage = (double) (processCpuTime - lastProcessCpuTime ) / ( systemTime - lastSystemTime )*100.0;

            lastSystemTime     = systemTime;
            lastProcessCpuTime = processCpuTime;

            return cpuUsage / availableProcessors;
        }

        private void baselineCounters()
        {
            lastSystemTime = System.nanoTime();

            lastProcessCpuTime = ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean().getCurrentThreadCpuTime();
        }



        }
```

and i am using this class in my code ,

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {

             monitor = new PerformanceMonitor();
            for(int i=0 ; i<10000 ; i++){
                start();
                double usage = monitor.getCpuUsage();
                if(usage!=0)System.out.println("Current CPU usage in pourcentage : "+usage);
            }
        }

        private static void start() {
            int count=0;
            for(int i=0 ; i<100000 ; i++){
                count=(int) Math.random()*100;
            }
        }
}
```

i am getting output like this,

```
Current CPU usage in pourcentage : 114.32926829268293
Current CPU usage in pourcentage : 48.70208931963182
Current CPU usage in pourcentage : 193.08746862328633
Current CPU usage in pourcentage : 236.85457129322594
```

hopes for your suggestions thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the interval is too short. The cpu counters on linux only update 100 times per second and you could be performing the loop in about 1/100th of a second meaning you get a very large error.  Try increasing the length of the loop so it is a few seconds long.

---

I made the test longer and removed the `/ availableProcessors` and I get numbers like this

```
Current CPU usage in percentage : 99.95763231535723
Current CPU usage in percentage : 99.94895863534565
Current CPU usage in percentage : 99.40642907762789
Current CPU usage in percentage : 99.96184668521532
Current CPU usage in percentage : 99.89017532820115
Current CPU usage in percentage : 99.91157680329947
Current CPU usage in percentage : 99.96919753553432
Current CPU usage in percentage : 99.94121334997978
```

Comment: i have not understand what are you trying to tell me as i am getting values because there ia a while loop actually i will have to get only one value then what will happen if it base on loop time duration ?

Comment: The shorter the period the less accurate your result.  For durations close to 0.01 seconds it is very inaccurate and less than this it is meaningless.

Comment: Pete i want to get this value once after 5 minutes then again one value after 5 minute then for this patren what should i do to get accurate value??

Comment: and how would i increase its loop time means where in my code?

Comment: 5 minutes is more than enough. I ran for about 5 seconds . ;)

Comment: In your `start()` make the loop counter bigger, nothing complicated about it. ;). i.e. instead of `100000` make it `100000000`

Comment: Peter you are awsome man i have got it but now i am getting values of percentage in the range of 20... :)

Comment: i am getting these values (Current CPU usage in pourcentage : 24.076833992637305
Current CPU usage in pourcentage : 23.805637174883014
Current CPU usage in pourcentage : 25.369764314889515
Current CPU usage in pourcentage : 24.837247039538138)

Comment: I assume you didn't remove the `/ availableProcessors` as I suggested. ;)

Comment: yup you are right i did it correct and then i am getting these values(Current CPU usage in pourcentage : 99.14144643677403
Current CPU usage in pourcentage : 99.89674561376977
Current CPU usage in pourcentage : 99.77564897427172
Current CPU usage in pourcentage : 100.20222886806567
Current CPU usage in pourcentage : 99.79781076305294
Current CPU usage in pourcentage : 99.7727800347421)

Comment: in these there is one 100+ value  also :(

Comment: As you can see, there is a small error which will get smaller the longer you run the test.  What happen here is you started a test just after the CPU counter ticked and stopped just after it ticked. e.g. say the count was 101 counts but the runtime was actually 100.1 counts, you will appear to get ~ 101% CPU. Sometimes if you run for 100.9 ticks you will see only 100 counts resulting in a ~99% CPU utilisation.